# Excel Power Query - Dynamics 365 Online - get names from another table without Merge

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm, powerquery

I am pulling some Opportunities from our Dyn365 instance into Excel using the Get Data From Dynamics 365 (online) feature. Some columns (i.e. Account, Seller, etc.) show GUIDs rather than names and in order to see names I need to use Merge Queries and pull the relevant tables into Excel.

[image]

Problem is, the Accounts table has ~800k records and the Sellers table isn't small either so even if I reduce the number of columns to load, it still takes about 7 minutes to refresh this query. My questions:

1. Can this be achieved without the need for merging tables?
2. Or, can I use merge, but not have to load Accounts and Sellers into worksheet?
3. Is there a better way to do what i'm trying to do?
   (except for the Dynamic Worksheet Export)?

//Edited 31-May-2022

M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Opportunities"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"OpportunityID", type text}, {"OpportunityNumber", type text}, {"Account", type text}, {"Seller", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.Buffer(Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Account"}, Accounts, {"AccountID"}, "Accounts", JoinKind.LeftOuter)),
    #"Expanded Accounts" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Accounts", {"CustomerName", "Country"}, {"Accounts.CustomerName", "Accounts.Country"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.Buffer(Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Accounts", {"Seller"}, Sellers, {"SellerID"}, "Sellers", JoinKind.LeftOuter)),
    #"Expanded Sellers" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Sellers", {"SellerName"}, {"Sellers.SellerName"})
in
    #"Expanded Sellers"
```

//Edit2 - the below doesn't even want to load into preview (i.e. marching ants forever). Without the "Table.Buffer()" the preview loads within seconds.

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    #"BufferedOpportunities" = Table.Buffer(Source{[Name="opportunities",Signature="table"]}[Data])
in
    #"BufferedOpportunities"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding point 2:

2. You can merge without loading the Accounts and Sellers tables into a worksheet. You can right click the query in the Queries & Connections pane in Excel and ensure you tick Only Create Connection for each of those two queries. The tables will then be unloaded from the workbook which will save a lot of time.

[image]

Edit:

Try this. I have typed it freehand so can't guarantee no mistakes but it should give you an idea of what you need to do.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Opportunities"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.Buffer( Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"OpportunityID", type text}, {"OpportunityNumber", type text}, {"Account", type text}, {"Seller", type text}})),
    BufferedAccounts = Table.Buffer(Accounts),
    BufferedSellers = Table.Buffer(Sellers),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Account"}, BufferedAccounts, {"AccountID"}, "Accounts", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Accounts" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Accounts", {"CustomerName", "Country"}, {"Accounts.CustomerName", "Accounts.Country"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Accounts", {"Seller"}, BufferedSellers, {"SellerID"}, "Sellers", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Sellers" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Sellers", {"SellerName"}, {"Sellers.SellerName"})
in
    #"Expanded Sellers"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and then merged tables as before, but that still causes the merged table to load at a painflly slow speed of about 20 rows per minute. Unmerged, my 800 Opportunities load within 10 seconds.

Comment: You need to buffer the table that you are merging using Table.Buffer(). That will bring it all into memory rather than streaming 1 at a time.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, it still takes several minutes to load. I added my code above, could you confirm that I am adding the "Table.Buffer()" in the right places, please?

Comment: They're not in the correct place. I'll edit my answer as I can't type code in a comment box.

Comment: It doesn't work, i'm afraid, see my Edit#2 above. From reading about Table.Buffer() online it doesn't seem to always improve performance, and it certainly doesn't in my case. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, there is another option. OData is always a pain with PQ. What you can do is load the entire OData table into a dataflow once a day (or whatever frequency you need) and then connect your Power BI query to that dataflow. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-create

Comment: So I tired your suggestion and it worked! But then, after playing with the DataFlows for a while, I realized that I can connect from Excel directly to the Dataverse so I don't even need the DataFlow. The Dataverse data pull is very fast comparing with OData even with my mergings. Thank you so much for helping me figure this out. I'll accept your answer now!

Comment: Great stuff - glad we got there in the end. :)